# What is difference between "first_open" and "session_start" in funnel exploration in Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I created a funnel exloration with some events to check users drop of my android game. I found that there is a big drop between first_open and session_start event. There maybe some crashes or bad features between these two events such as game loading, intro, etc. I'm confusing about the definitions of these 2 events in funnel exploration so I couldn't know what happens between these 2.
Here is the funnel image:

[image]

I just know that an user can trigger 1 first_open event, more than 1 session_start. But in GA funnel, it counts user, not how many events triggerd.

Anybody who can give me more info on that? Thanks!

Comment: show screenshot please

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BBOutw0.png , here is the screenshot of funnel I'm checking, please check and help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy may depend on the timeframe you are looking at.

If you look at a recent period there shouldn't be any differences, if you look at a past period there could be because session_start started.

Previously the Google documentation seemed to say that Google Analytics for Firebase would trigger a `session_start` event if there was no current session, **and the app was in the foreground for more than 10 seconds**.

Currently, Google Analytics for Firebase will trigger a `session_start` event as soon as your app goes into the foreground now. **There’s no more 10 second delay**: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9191807?hl=en

Therefore from a certain period onwards you should no longer see that problem (in fact it is like this in my Analytics)